# Ошибка в модели Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

Не знаю по какой причине возникает ошибка при сохранении модели:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean

Модель выглядит так:

```
class Brain_CrownCaliber_Model_Processcrown extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
       $this->_init('brain_crowncaliber/crown_caliber_process');
    }

    public function addProductToCrown($idArray)
    {
        foreach ($idArray as $id) {
            $this->setData('product_id', $id);
        }
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $this->save();
    }

}
```

Регистрирую её в `config.xml`:

```
<models>
            <brain_crowncaliber>
                <class>Brain_CrownCaliber_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>brain_crowncaliber_resource</resourceModel>
            </brain_crowncaliber>
</models>
```

**В чем может бить проблема ?** Даже не понимаю в чем я могу ошибаться здесь

Секция ресурса:

```
<brain_crowncaliber_resource>
                    <class>HexBrain_CrownCaliber_Model_Resource</class>
                    <entities>
                        <crown_caliber_process>
                            <table>crown_caliber_process</table>
                        </crown_caliber_process>
                    </entities>
</brain_crowncaliber_resource>
```

Модель ресурса

```
class Brain_CrownCaliber_Model_Resource_Processcrown extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('brain_crowncaliber/crown_caliber_process', 'process_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: не проходит инициализация `_construct()` на php `__construct()` попробуй заменить.

Comment: @Naumov, не дало результатов ( Ошибка не изменилась

Comment: Секцию где resurcModel преведи из конфига эту `brain_crowncaliber_resource`

Comment: @Naumov, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: код resource_model где?

Comment: @Naumov, добавил в вопрос

Comment: Погодь а что ты пытаешься этим сделать addProductToCrown? мало того что ты вызываешь save не у инициализированной модели, так и id только последний устанавливаеться?

Comment: @Naumov, хочу добавить новую запись в таблицу и сохранить!

Comment: Попробуй за пределами модели это сделать или глупо звучит но сделай в самой моделе `$blabla = Mage::getModel('blabla/blalb')` что бы получить иницированый инстанс модели.

Comment: @Naumov, вот только что попробовал та сделать и новая ошибка  - _Call to a member function setData() on boolean_

Comment: Пройди в метод getModel там будет метод getClassName и т.д. видимо класс формируеться не правильный,

Comment: Ну да смотри сдесь `<class>HexBrain_CrownCaliber_Model_Resource</class>` какой то HexBrain а тут `Brain_CrownCaliber_Model_Resource_Processcrown` просто Brain,  т.е. если это так то класс не ресолвиться.

Comment: @Naumov, это я ошибку допустил на форуме а не в коде! Случайно не удалил "Hex"

Comment: Дошол до кода формирования имени класса всё правильно формируеться?

Comment: @Naumov, вот так у меня выглядит getModel:
`public static function getModel($modelClass = '', $arguments = array())
    {
        return self::getConfig()->getModelInstance($modelClass, $arguments);
    }`

а `getClassName` метода в этом классе нет

Comment: @Naumov, это скорее всего что то с моей моделью или не правильно инстал скрипт сделал! Потому что даже такие методы модели не работают как getCollection, getData и тд. Проверил - сделал модель продукта, все работает: данные достаются, изменяются!

Comment: в конфиге опечатка где то.

Comment: Отпишись исправил?  Что было? Что бы ответ дополнить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформлю как ответом потому как коментарий не позволяет форматировать нормально

вот метод в файле `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` строка 1349

```
/**
 * Get model class instance.
 *
 * Example:
 * $config->getModelInstance('catalog/product')
 *
 * Will instantiate Mage_Catalog_Model_Mysql4_Product
 *
 * @param string $modelClass
 * @param array|object $constructArguments
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract|false
 */
public function getModelInstance($modelClass='', $constructArguments=array())
{
    $className = $this->getModelClassName($modelClass);
    if (class_exists($className)) {
        Varien_Profiler::start('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
        $obj = new $className($constructArguments);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
        return $obj;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

сделай `var_dump($className)` что бы посмотретть какое име класа сформировалось, оно скорее всего неправильное. Идём дальше в метод `getModelClassName()` в общем доходим до метода 1219 этого же файла `getGroupedClassName()`

```
 /**
     * Retrieve class name by class group
     *
     * @param   string $groupType currently supported model, block, helper
     * @param   string $classId slash separated class identifier, ex. group/class
     * @param   string $groupRootNode optional config path for group config
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode=null)
    {
        if (empty($groupRootNode)) {
            $groupRootNode = 'global/'.$groupType.'s';
        }

        $classArr = explode('/', trim($classId));
        $group = $classArr[0];
        $class = !empty($classArr[1]) ? $classArr[1] : null;

        if (isset($this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class])) {
            return $this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class];
        }

        $config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};

        // First - check maybe the entity class was rewritten
        $className = null;
        if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
            $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
        } else {
            /**
             * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
             * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
             * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
             */
            if ($config->deprecatedNode) {
                $deprecatedNode = $config->deprecatedNode;
                $configOld = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->$deprecatedNode;
                if (isset($configOld->rewrite->$class)) {
                    $className = (string) $configOld->rewrite->$class;
                }
            }
        }

        // Second - if entity is not rewritten then use class prefix to form class name
        if (empty($className)) {
            if (!empty($config)) {
                $className = $config->getClassName();
            }
            if (empty($className)) {
                $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
            }
            if (!empty($class)) {
                $className .= '_'.$class;
            }
            $className = uc_words($className);
        }

        $this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class] = $className;
        return $className;
    }
```

что этот метод делает, берёт из конфига име prefix класса который указан в секции `models` в общем после того как ты увидешь сформированное име класса ты поймёшь где ошибка. Но по опыту скажу гдее то в конфиге опечатка. В принципе отредактированный вариант на СО должен работать.

Comment: Очень благодарен за то, что помогли разобраться! Была ошибка сначала в конфиге (немного напутал с узлами моделей). И в самой модели не правильно namespace указал!! )